# Find root folder of workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba, dropbox

I am trying to get to the root folder of a workbook which is Dropbox

I have this code which does the job but i am wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing it

```
DropboxPath = Left(ThisWorkbook.path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.path, "Dropbox") + 6)
```

[image]

What im trying to do is remove everything after Dropbox

Thanks

Comment: What is it that youre trying to do?  Can you show an example path?  Doesn't your code just return `ThisWorkbook.path`?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Hi, edited post. Hopefully clearer

Comment: `Debug.Print Mid(s, 1, InStrRev(s, "dropbox") + Len("dropbox") - 1)`

Comment: Since the name of the dropbox folder can change, this [link](https://help.dropbox.com/en-gb/installs-integrations/desktop/locate-dropbox-folder) explain how to get the location of the Dropbox folder. It is stored in a json file you can parse to retrieve the location.